# Получить строку DataGrid из Usercontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm

У меня есть столбец в DataGrid который содержит DropDownButton. Не получается по нажатию кнопки в DropDownButton получить строку DataGrid.

Код:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColemnHeaderStyle}" Width="125">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <control:DropDownButton Height="36" Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle}">
                            <control:DropDownButton.Menu>
                                <ContextMenu ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"
                                             Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}" Placement="Bottom">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Подробно" Command="{Binding Send}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid},Path=DataContext}"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Написать"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Отправить контакт"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </control:DropDownButton.Menu>
                        </control:DropDownButton>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, если прописать так:

```
<MenuItem Header="Подробно" Command="{Binding DataContext.Send, Source={x:Reference data}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

где DataGrid x:Name="data"